# python cannot marshal <class 'decimal.Decimal'> objects

Tags: python

I updated my OS to Centos 7. Now I have Python 2.7.

Below code was work in Python 2.6 but now it doesn't work.

```
OS: Centos 7
Python 2.7.5
Apache/2.4.6
```

My do_POST is:

```
def do_POST(self):
    """Handles the HTTP POST request.

    Attempts to interpret all HTTP POST requests as XML-RPC calls,
    which are forwarded to the _dispatch method for handling.
    """

    try:
        # get arguments
        data = self.rfile.read(int(self.headers["content-length"]))
        params, method = xmlrpclib.loads(data)

        # generate response
        try:
            response = self._dispatch(method, params)
            # wrap response in a singleton tuple
            response = (response,)
        except XMLRPCFault:
            # report exception back to server
            response = xmlrpclib.dumps(
                xmlrpclib.Fault(1, "%s" % (sys.exc_info()[1]))
                )
        else:
            response = xmlrpclib.dumps(response, methodresponse=1)
    except:
        logException(LOG_ERROR,"XMLRPCServer")
        # internal error, report as HTTP server error
        self.send_response(500)
        self.end_headers()
    else:
        # got a valid XML RPC response
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/xml")
        self.send_header("Content-length", str(len(response)))
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(response)

        # shut down the connection
        self.wfile.flush()
        self.connection.shutdown(1)
```

The error is :

```
2015/08/15-11:49:36 XMLRPCServer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/IBSng/core/server/xmlrpcserver.py", line 53, in do_POST
    response = xmlrpclib.dumps(response, methodresponse=1)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1085, in dumps
    data = m.dumps(params)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 632, in dumps
    dump(v, write)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 654, in __dump
    f(self, value, write)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 735, in dump_struct
    dump(v, write)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 654, in __dump
    f(self, value, write)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 735, in dump_struct
    dump(v, write)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 654, in __dump
    f(self, value, write)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 735, in dump_struct
    dump(v, write)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 646, in __dump
    raise TypeError, "cannot marshal %s objects" % type(value)
TypeError: cannot marshal <class 'decimal.Decimal'> objects
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `xmlrpclib` module doesn't support `decimal.Decimal` objects out of the box, no.

You have two options: convert the `Decimal` objects to floats first, or extend the marshaller to handle `Decimal` objects explicitly.

Converting the `Decimal` object is as simple as:

```
from decimal import Decimal

# ..
def convert_decimal_to_float(ob):
    if isinstance(ob, Decimal):
        return float(ob)
    if isinstance(ob, (tuple, list)):
        return [convert_decimal_to_float(v) for v in ob]
    if isinstance(ob, dict):
        return {k: convert_decimal_to_float(v) for k, v in ob.iteritems()}
    return ob

response = self._dispatch(method, params)
response = (convert_decimal_to_float(response),)
```

Adding support to the library looks like this:

```
from xmlrpclib import Marshaller
from decimal import Decimal

def dump_decimal(self, value, write):
    write("<value><double>")
    write(str(value))
    write("</double></value>\n")

Marshaller.dispatch[Decimal] = dump_decimal
```

Comment: or a third option -- convert the `Decimal` object to a a string first, then convert back to a `Decimal` afterwards

Comment: @MarkChackerian: but that'd require support on the XML-RPC server side to accept such string values.

Comment: yes -- only a viable option if you can change server end.